# How to print json array values in html table using php code

Tags: php, json

```
`a:14:{s:9:"user_name";s:5:"vijay";s:10:"user_email";s:26:"vijayk@gmail.com";s:9:"user_pass";s:10:"vijayk";s:4:"role";s:10:"subscriber";s:11:"firstname_1";s:5:"vijay";s:10:"lastname_2";s:7:"kolhe";s:13:"collegename_4";s:7:"abcd";s:15:"currentstatus_5";s:7:"Student";s:13:"passoutyear_7";s:4:"2015";s:8:"branch_8";s:2:"IT";s:6:"year_9";s:2:"FE";s:12:"contactno_10";s:10:"1234567890";s:7:"User_IP";s:3:"::1";s:7:"Browser";s:109:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36";}`
```

I want to print this json array data in html table format such as column names are First Name, Lastname, College Name etc and values are vijay, kolhe, abcd respectively.

Comment: This isn't a JSON array. It's an object and it's missing some quotes, see the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) for details.

Comment: I think this is a serialize [http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php] see this.

Comment: I got this as output: [[],{"value":"a:14{s:9:\"user_name\";s:5:\"vijay\";s:10:\"user_email\";s:26:\"vijay@gmail.com\";s:9:\"user_pass\";s:10:\"vijayk\";s:4:\"role\";s:10:\"subscriber\";s:11:\"firstname_1\";s:5:\"vijay\";s:10:\"lastname_2\";s:7:\"kolhe\";s:13:\"collegename_4\";s:7:\"abcdtech\";s:15:\"currentstatus_5\";s:7:\"Student\";s:13:\"passoutyear_7\";s:4:\"2015\";s:8:\"branch_8\";s:2:\"IT\";s:6:\"year_9\";s:2:\"FE\";s:12:\"contactno_10\";s:10:\"1234567890\";}"}]

Comment: @SwapnilKachare can you paste whole data in your question? it will be helpful for other to check and give solution.

Comment: i have used this code   <?php
//open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select value from wp_crf_entries";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
     
    
    //create an array
    $emparray[] = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
       
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);
   
   
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>

Answer (score -1):

If your JSON data is correctly formed, this should do it:

```
<?php
//JSON in standard format
$jsonData = '{
    "user_name" : "vijay",
    "user_email" : "vijayk@gmail.com",
    "user_pass" : "vijayk",
    "role" : "subscriber",
    "firstname_1" : "vijay",
    "lastname_2" : "kolhe",
    "collegename_4" :"abcd",
    "currentstatus_5" : "Student",
    "passoutyear_7" : "2015",
    "branch_8" : "IT",
    "year_9" : "FE",
    "contactno_10" : "1234567890",
    "User_IP" : "::1",
    "Browser" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36" }';

//decode json data
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonData);

//create table
$tbl = '<table>';
$tbl .= '<tr>';
//loop for the column names
foreach ($jsonDecoded as $key => $value) {
    $tbl .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
}
$tbl .= '</tr>';

$tbl .= '<tr>';
//loop for the column values
foreach ($jsonDecoded as $key => $value) {
    $tbl .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
}
$tbl .= '</tr>';
$tbl .= '</table>';

echo $tbl; //see below table result:

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>user_name</td>
        <td>user_email</td>
        <td>user_pass</td>
        <td>role</td>
        <td>firstname_1</td>
        <td>lastname_2</td>
        <td>collegename_4</td>
        <td>currentstatus_5</td>
        <td>passoutyear_7</td>
        <td>branch_8</td>
        <td>year_9</td>
        <td>contactno_10</td>
        <td>User_IP</td>
        <td>Browser</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>vijay</td>
        <td>vijayk@gmail.com</td>
        <td>vijayk</td>
        <td>subscriber</td>
        <td>vijay</td>
        <td>kolhe</td>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>Student</td>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>FE</td>
        <td>1234567890</td>
        <td>::1</td>
        <td>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not a json string!

Comment: That's why I say in the beginning "if your JSON data is correctly formed". No need to downvote my answer when his question is "how to print JSON array values..."

Comment: It's not even bad formatted JSON at all. It's a serialized string.